# Greek characters and images using iText and htmlWorker

Tags: java, playframework, itext

I have the following piece of code for a PDF export in a web application that creates a PDF with a 2x2 table cell.

```
public static void myexport2() throws IOException{
    try {
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C://Users/gkarapatis/Desktop/testpdf.pdf"));
        document.open();
        document.addAuthor("Author of the Doc");
        document.addCreator("Creator of the Doc");
        document.addSubject("Subject of the Doc");
        document.addCreationDate();
        document.addTitle("This is the title");
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
        String str="<table height=300, border=\"1\"><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td></td></tr></table>"     

        htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
        document.close();
    } catch(DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I am adding greek characters to the HTML cell it does not appear to the exporting PDF file. What should I do in order to add Unicode to my export.
Is it an issue of HTMLWorker ?

When I am trying to add an image to a cell adding the

```
img src=\"file://C:/Webapp/dsp/public/images/dsp1.jpg\" width=\"80\" height=\"81\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\"
```

It throws me an exception.
I am using play framework and the exception it throws is "InvocationTargetException occured : null "

Comment: Is it possible that it is a matter of the font you are using? Have you tried specifying a font which has greek characters?

Comment: I am using play framework and the exception its throws is InvocationTargetException occured : null

Comment: I tried to specifying a unicode fond but probably not in right way... Could someone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

As far you are creating table better to do it using PdfPTable.Creating cell is simpler just as you adding cell by cell(each cell is PdfPCell).Now concerning your two problem

1. use specific font to display greek character.As you are embed it as unicode better to try it using Arialuni.ttf.Then if you found specific font use that.
2. Add image to cell is also simple just use add method of PdfPCell.Creating font for implementation,you have to create font using BaseFont class.(Just google it out for each part,to understand better.)Exported pdf not displaying those greek character because of it can't find the glyph that represented by the code point(Unicode).

If you can attach a image of what will be the expected output we can give some insight.